# Login.aspx: i have to check the userID, Password as well as the title of the user

Tags: c#, asp.net

actually, i have 3 users of the system namely the administrator, director and members. thus i have 3 different homepages. when logging into the system i want to check the ID and password as well as check the title of the specific ID so as to redirect them to the appropriate homepages. but it is not working, here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;



namespace CTIPerfAppraisalSystFINAL
{
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationCTIConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "Select count(*) from [tblEmployee] where UserID= '" + txt_userID + "'";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);

        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp != 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPassword = "Select Password from [tblEmployee] where UserID= @ID";
            SqlCommand Pass = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
            Pass.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", txt_userID.Text));
            string Password = Pass.ExecuteScalar() as string;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password)) Password.Replace(" ", "");

            if (Password == txt_password.Text)
            {
                if ( string checktitle="Select Title from [tblEmployee] where Title='Administrator'")
                {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checktitle, conn);
                Session["New"] = txt_userID.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct.");
                Response.Redirect("~/Administrator Home Page.aspx");
                conn.Close();
                }

                if ( string checktitle="Select Title from [tblEmployee] where Title='Director'")
                {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checktitle, conn);
                Session["New"] = txt_userID.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct.");
                Response.Redirect("~/Director Home Page.aspx");
                conn.Close();
                }


                if ( string checktitle="Select Title from [tblEmployee] where Title='Member'");
                {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checktitle, conn);
                Session["New"] = txt_userID.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is correct.");
                Response.Redirect("~/Member Home Page.aspx");
                conn.Close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Login is incorrect.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Describe "not working". You need to tell us exactly what the issue is.

Comment: What's not working? Error details are very helpful.

Comment: Actually it is not checking the user title, it is redirecting all users to the administrator homepage only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating things that are really simple. Just call a single select for the Title field and pass in the WHERE clause the condition to be met. (UserID and Password).
Call the ExecuteReader to get back the Title if the condition in the WHERE clause is met. 
At this point it is just a matter to check what title you got back and jump to the appropriate page

```
protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string cmdText = @"Select Title 
                           from [tblEmployee] 
                           where UserID= @id AND Password = @pwd";

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_userID.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", txt_password.Text);
        using(SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                string title = reader["Title"].ToString();
                switch(title)
                {
                    case "Administrator":
                       Session["New"] = txt_userID.Text;
                       Response.Write("Password is correct.");
                       Response.Redirect("~/Administrator Home Page.aspx");
                       break;
                    case "Director":
                       Session["New"] = txt_userID.Text;
                       Response.Write("Password is correct.");
                       Response.Redirect("~/Director Home Page.aspx");
                       break;
                    case "Member":
                       Session["New"] = txt_userID.Text;
                       Response.Write("Password is correct.");
                       Response.Redirect("~/Member Home Page.aspx");
                       break;
                    default:
                       Response.Write("Unknown title: " + title);
                       break;
                }
           }
           else
              Response.Write("Login is incorrect.");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
if ( string checktitle="Select Title from [tblEmployee] where Title='Administrator'")
```

will always be `true`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are concatenating the variable "txt_userID" with your Sql instead of "txt_userID.Text". Later in the code it looks like you do it "correctly".

BTW: never concatenate strings, even if it's not production code - always use a parameter, or you're inviting to get SQL Injected.

Comment: corrected this mistake, but still it is redirecting all users to the administrator homepage only.